# Add indicator to the title of an calendar event to show that it has an attachment

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-foundation

Looking for options:

I want to set it up so that when a person attaches a document to an event of a calendar list that the title of said event will be modified with an indicator to show that a file has been attached.  Any ideas are appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a column called attached indicator that was set through a workflow that had the following code in the onWorkflowActivated_Invoked

```
private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        SPListItem item = workflowProperties.Item;

        if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
            item["AttachmentIndicator"] = "inline";
        }
        else
        {
            item["AttachmentIndicator"] = "none";
        }
        item.Update();
    }
```

The value of the AttachmentIndicator was used in a calculated column called Display with an  tag.  It set the display CSS style on the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but can you try to use [this technic](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html) to customize view?

Comment: The SharePoint calendars are built with JavaScript, not xslt.